how to make span take up entire height of div
I have this group of spans that are supposed to serve as selectors, so I want them to take up the entire space around them when the user hovers over them, however I have no idea how and could not find an answer to this. please help, here's my code
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.selector  {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.link  {
    background-color:LightGray;
    color:black;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div class="link"><b>
    
<span onmouseover= 'style="background-color:white;"' onmouseout= 'style="background-color:LightGray;"' style="color:black;" class="selector">Prehrana</span>
<span onmouseover= 'style="background-color:white;"' onmouseout= 'style="background-color:LightGray;"' style="color:black;" class="selector">Pica</span>
<span onmouseover= 'style="background-color:white;"' onmouseout= 'style="background-color:LightGray;"' style="color:black;" class="selector">Ciscenje  </span>
<span onmouseover= 'style="background-color:white;"' onmouseout= 'style="background-color:LightGray;"' style="color:black;" class="selector">Drugo</span>
<span onmouseover= 'style="background-color:white;"' onmouseout= 'style="background-color:LightGray;"' style="color:black;" class="selector">Akcija</span>

</b></div>

the text inside the span is croatian. This is also my first website that I am making with no assistance so don't make fun of me please.

Please don't add Solved to your title, or post your solution in the question. You can provide a self-answer by posting in the answers section below.

Ok, gotcha. Didn't know that

No worries at all, and welcome to SO

I solved it by adding
padding-top: 10px
padding-bottom: 10px
margin: -10;

to the selector class

Set link to have a fixed size.
Remove padding specified in link.
Set selector:hover to have 100% height.
I also moved your styles from the html into the css file.


*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.selector  {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display:inline-block;

    /* EDIT Moved here from html */
    color: black;
}

/* EDIT Control hover (replaces your mouseover and mouseout) */
.selector:hover  {
  background-color: white;

  height: 100%;
}

.link  {
    background-color:LightGray;
    color:black;
    /* EDIT Remove padding here, so we can control spacing with margin in .selector */
    /* padding: 5px; */
    font-size: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;

    /* EDIT Need to have a fixed size */
    height: 3rem;
}
<div class="link"><b>
  <!-- EDIT Moved your style's to the .css file -->
  <span class="selector">Prehrana</span>
  <span class="selector">Pica</span>
  <span class="selector">Ciscenje  </span>
  <span class="selector">Drugo</span>
  <span class="selector">Akcija</span>
</b></div>




Try this


*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.selector {
    padding:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.link {
    background-color: LightGray;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px; 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
}

.selector:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="link">
        <b>
            <span class="selector">Prehrana</span>
            <span class="selector">Pica</span>
            <span class="selector">Ciscenje</span>
            <span class="selector">Drugo</span>
            <span class="selector">Akcija</span>
        </b>
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>




remove padding from .link class
and put normal padding to the .selector class

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
